# Geometry of Skew-Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, hermitian-matrices

In the question I will be referring to finite dimensional complex vector spaces. I know that the eigenvalues of an Skew-Hermitian matrix $S$ are purely imaginary, but what is their geometric effect on the vector space? I know that Hermitian matrices H have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors which span the whole vector space and their eigenvalues are purely real. Their effect is as far as I understand that Hermitian matrices $H$ just scale the vector space in the direction of these orthogonal eigenvectors by the eigenvalues and have no rotational effect. Is the effect of Skew-Hermitian matrices then just purely rotational?

Comment: Note that in order to define Hermitian/skew-Hermitian operators on a vector space, it is important that that the vector spaces that you mention have an inner product. That said, if we're considering matrices, that inner product is implicitly defined

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite correct.

It's helpful to first establish that because we are in a complex vector space, the one-dimensional subspaces are two dimensional spaces relative to multiplication by real numbers, and so is perhaps best visualized as a two-dimensional space. Within the span of any single non-zero vector, multiplication by $e^{i \theta}$ corresponds to a rotation (within this "one-dimensional" span) by an angle of $\theta$.

Skew-Hermitian matrices have purely imaginary eigenvalues, and just like Hermitian matrices, they can be unitarily diagonalized. So, for any skew-Hermitian matrix $A$, there is an orthonormal basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ such that $A v_j = \pm i\lambda_j v_j$ for some $\lambda_j \geq 0$. So, we have broken up $\Bbb C^n$ as the direct sum of $n$ mutually orthogonal "1-dimensional" vector spaces, each the span of an eigenvector $v_j$. Within the span of $v_j$, the action of $A$ can be thought of as a multiplication by $\pm i$ (a rotation by $90^\circ$) followed by scaling by factor $\lambda_j$.

---

Another helpful perspective comes from the study of Lie Groups. The unitary matrices may be thought of as corresponding to rotations within $\Bbb C^n$. Unitary matrices are also unitarily diagonalizable; for any unitary matrix $M$, there exists an orthonormal basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ such that $Mv_j = e^{i \theta_j}v_j$ for some $\theta_j \in \Bbb R$. In other words, within each of $n$ mutually orthogonal "1-dimensional" vector spaces, the action of $M$ is a rotation by angle $\theta$.

The skew-Hermitian matrices, in a sense, correspond to "infinitesimal rotations". If $A$ is skew-Hermitian, then $(I + \frac An)^n$ (for positive integer $n$) is approximately a rotation. In the limit as $n \to \infty$, we find that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(I + \frac An\right)^n = e^A
$$
is a unitary matrix. In fact, for every $M$, there exists a Hermitian matrix $A$ that "generates" $M$ in this sense.

Another helpful perspective: we can extend our description of $M$ to describe an entire family of rotations (called a "one parameter subgroup"). For any $t \in \Bbb R$, we'll say that $M(t)$ is the matrix for which $M(t) v_j = e^{it\theta_j} v_j$. Notably, $M(0) = I$ and $M(1) = M$ (the first unitary matrix we described). The "derivative" of this function of $t$ at $t = 0$ yields another transformation, and this transformation corresponds to a skew-Hermitian matrix. In particular, for each $j$,
$$
\left.\frac d{dt} e^{it \theta_j}v_j\right|_{t = 0} = i\theta_j v_j.
$$
In this way, the Hermitian matrices correspond to the "tangent space" of the set of unitary matrices at the point $I$.